# Put Imageviews side by side android studio

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

i want to create a layout like in this picture,
[See it my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywSLE.jpg)

so for that i did with LinearLayout but i have this for result:

[See it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL9ge.jpg)

so please how i need your help to reach my goal,

Comment: You can use a staggered grid view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve that with `LinearLayout`.

you need to use [StaggeredGridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager) to achieve that result.

For demo You can [use this](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

Comment: @Antonely93 if you issue is solved you can accept the answer and let me know if you stuck somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Use Staggered GridView for your layout..It will solve your problem.

- StaggeredGridView is like GridView but in GridView you can show data in Same size boxes , where in StraggeredGridView you can show data in different size of boxes , like you give image in your question .

  1. LinearLayoutManager: It is used for displaying Vertical or Horizontal List.
  2. GridLayoutManager: It is used for displaying the items in the form of Grids.
  3. StaggeredGridLayoutManager: It is used to show the items in staggered Grid.

[Here is the example of staggered-grid](https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

The layout you showed in the picture is called `staggered gridview` and for implementing that you can find an example [here](http://www.androidcoding.in/2018/04/01/android-staggered-gridview-tutorial/).